# How can I use for (ever){} instead of for (;;) in Java

Tags: java

I'd like to use an infinite loop in Java: `for (;;)` and I think it would look amusing if I could replace that `';;'` with the variable `'ever'`
like this:

```
String ever = ";;";
for(ever){
...
}
```

Is such a thing possible in Java?

Comment: `while (true) {}`?? Tooo Localized.

Comment: [Nop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1). Your question probably ticks a few boxes of the "What not to ask" list of the FAQ...

Comment: Amusing it may be but other than that, what advantage would it give us?

Comment: you can´t to it like you try it there, the for loop wont do a `code replacment` if it finds only one argument

Comment: @biziclop The idea is that it's self-documenting code. It's an old `C` idea, where you have macros so it is possible.

Comment: btw i think he wants to do something like in C, where you can tell the preprozessor some defined code, and it will do some `code replacement`

Comment: Why oh why did they not do macros in Java?!  We could have done THIS!!

Comment: You can do `boolean ever = true;  for(;ever;) { }`

Comment: You're probably using the wrong language. If you want unpredictable, opaque text-replacements (macros), you should use C. Java deliberately does not allow this kind of thing because it is deemed possibly harmful.

Comment: @RB Any Java developer who can't read `for(;;)` or indeed the preferred `while(true)` should seriously consider a career change. I know it sounds harsh but it isn't.

Comment: @biziclop I never said I thought it was sensible!!! I'm just explaining where the idea comes from. Mostly it's an attempt at humour, but the (slim) justification is self-documenting code.

Comment: @RB I see, fair enough :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it is not possible.

The closest you can come is this:

```
final boolean ever = true;
for (;ever;) { }
```

Comment: Oh puhlease ... what a horrible idea.  You should be aiming to make your code readable as code ... not as English.  (It is clever though)

Answer (score 6):

When I obfuscate my programs due to a fear of syntax, I like to really rub it in...

```
for(ever;and;ever)
```

Where `and` is true and `ever` is whatever...

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
while (true) {

}
```

I know that you are going into code-art, but it's too expensive to do it this way.

I'm doing this kind of art sometimes too replacing `for` with `while`:

```
int counter = 4;
while (counter-->0) {
  // couter decrements from 4 to 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a syntax error!

This one-statement only works with while/do while loop.

Something like this:

```
 while(ever)
 { ..

 // some statement to change ever
 }
```